# FQL query doesn't return the correct results

Tags: facebook-fql

I'm running the following fql query in the graph explorer:
select album_object_id, object_id, aid, pid from photo where object_id=576544082370719

and i get the correct results i want:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "album_object_id": 520085011349960, 
      "object_id": 576544082370719, 
      "aid": "396713620353767_120902", 
      "pid": "396713620353767_2121634"
    }
  ]
}
```

however, when adding album_object_id to the statement, nothing is returned:
select album_object_id, object_id, aid, pid from photo where object_id=576544082370719 and album_object_id=520085011349960

```
{
  "data": [
  ]
}
```

anyone has any idea?
I tried to report it but they said they can't reproduce
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/448684285215430

here is another example which doesnt work but it supposed to, what is going on?
select object_id, modified from photo where object_id=507652032628572

this gives the correct result, however:
select object_id, modified from photo where album_object_id=468672926526483 and modified>1365522434

no results on this one.

Answer (score 0):

found out that when adding order by modified desc to the statement, results are fine, thats some kind of work around but well, at least works.